# Setting cookie after POST gives "undefined index" notice

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, cookies, setcookie

i have a setcookie function in php.
i have a jquery dialog with an input field an a submit button. when i type in a postcode in the input field and push submit the postcode is saved in an php cookie.

This cookie wil be shown in an input field on the mainpage.

Now is my problem that when i did not have a cookie set, so for example i leave the input field blank and click submit it gives me an error. but in the input field.

I am using codeigniter so that could be the problem.

Error:

> Message:  Undefined index:  name Filename: views/navmenu.php Line
>   Number: 33

My set cookie and form code:

```
<div id="dialog" class="hidden" title="Welkom bij OostWestRegioBest.nl">
Vul hier uw postcode in.
<form method="post" action"">
Postcode: <input type="text" name="name" size="25">
<input type="submit" value="Opslaan">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
</form>

<?php
// set the cookie with the submitted user data
setcookie('name', $_POST['name']);
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
    header("location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
    }
?>

</div>
```

My input field where the cookie will be shown at.

```
<input type="text" value='<?php echo $_COOKIE['name'] ?>'>
```

Hope someone could help me.

thanks.

Comment: You access `$_POST['name']` even when no form has been sent. Put the `setcookie()` line into the `if` block below and you should be fine.

Comment: Won't we need to see `views/navmenu.php` in order to answer this question?

Comment: the last line in the OP is from my navmenu.php but i solved it with Rohit Subedi's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the cookie only after the form is submitted

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
     setcookie('name', $_POST['name']);
}
```

You can change the input field as

```
<input type="text" value='<?php echo isset($_COOKIE['name']) ? $_COOKIE['name'] : '' ?>'>
```

Comment: this isn't right. because if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){ has to be if(isset($_POST['name'])){

Comment: your second code did work! Thanks to Vanga Sasidhar who pointed me at it.

Answer (score 1):

Set cookie only if $_POST contains an element with index - name.

You can try this.

```
<?php
    // set the cookie with the submitted user data
    setcookie('name', isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "");
?>
```

Or set cookie only if it contains an element with index - name.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
       // set the cookie with the submitted user data
       setcookie('name', $_POST['name']);
    }
?>
```

Choose any one based on your requirement.

Comment: The error is still shown. it is codeigniter related so can i somehow hide this error? because it's only a problem when no cookie is set.

Comment: Try the first one. It will set empty value in the cookie and same will be used in the input.

Comment: yeah but that's the problem. when it's empty it gives me the error. when it isn't empty it's fine.

Comment: As per the given error, which statement is at Line 33?

Comment: This one:  <input type="text" value='<?php echo $_COOKIE['name'] ?>'>

Comment: Then only try the second part of Rohit Subedi's solution. There we are actually checking whether a cookie with the index "name" exists or not. If exists, then it is showing that, else it is showing empty string.

Comment: upvoted you anyway because it's a good answer